# htaccess bitrix - На НЕКОТОРЫЕ из вложенных url не добавляется слэш в конце адреса

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, редирект

Есть сайт на 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 11.5.4. Древняя версия, конечно, но владелец не хочет ничего менять.

И есть проблема со слэшами в конце для определенных директорий.

**Слэш не добавляется в конец url-ов вида: https://site.ru/news/12345 и https://site.ru/media/12345**

На все остальные адреса слэш добавляется.
Помогите, пожалуйста, в указанных папках тоже настроить редирект на url со слэш в конце. А то у меня по SEO миллион ошибок из-за дублей страниц

Никаких дополнительных .htaccess в указанных папках /news/ и /media/ я не нашла, так что, видимо, не в этом дело.

А общий .htaccess вот

```
    Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

  #php_value display_errors 1

  #php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
  #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>


redirect 301 /services/addservices/такой-то файл/ /services/addservices/файл эдакий/


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/virtual_file_system.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/virtual_file_system.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]

</IfModule>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала несколько замечаний.

Во-первых, я вижу два правила с одним условием `"CONDITION" => "#^/news/#"`. Сработает только первое.

Во-вторых, если будете добавлять свои правила, то оставляйте ID пустым `"ID" => ""`. Так битрикс не перепишет их по своему разумению.

Итак, правило зависит от того, как ваш /news/index.php обрабатывает входные параметры. Допустим, он понимает параметр ID, и при обращении по адресу `/news/index.php?ID=12345` выдаёт нужную новость.

Тогда нам понадобятся два правила:

```
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/news/([0-9]+)/$#",
        "RULE" => "ID=$1",
        "ID" => "",
        "PATH" => "/news/index.php",
    ),
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/news/([0-9]+)/?(.*)$#",
        "RULE" => "ID=$1&$2",
        "ID" => "",
        "PATH" => "/news/index.php",
    ),
```

Второе правило - для переадресации в случае, когда в адресе будут какие-либо параметры. Чтобы понять эту запись, нужно разобраться с регулярными выражениями.
Кратко: CONDITION - регулярное выражение для поиска подходящих адресов, PATH - какая страница будет на самом деле всё обрабатывать, RULE - подстановка параметров (в данном случае $1 - то, что было в первых скобках, $2 - во вторых и так далее), ID - компонент, который создал правило (он же может его и поменять, поэтому ставим пустую строку).

Для media - аналогично.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить

```
# Add /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/[^/\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

после ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: Добавила. Но вместо добавления слэша в конец url происходит переадресация на несуществующую страницу https://site.ru/bitrix/urlrewrite.php

Comment: добавил RewriteEngine On

Comment: К сожалению, это тоже не дает искомого результата. Все также идет переадресация на 404-ю страницу site.ru/bitrix/urlrewrite.php

Comment: Переадресация на /bitrix/urlrewrite.php - это нормально. Но если она выдаёт 404, значит у вас в /urlrewrite.php не прописано правило для страниц /news/12345/ и /media/12345/ - со слэшем в конце.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подсказку. А что нужно туда дописать? Ниже прилагаю часть кода из этого файла, которая касается нужных мне url-ов

Comment: array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/media/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:news",
  "PATH" => "/media/index.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/news/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:news",
  "PATH" => "/news/index.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/news/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:media",
  "PATH" => "/СМИ о нас/СМИ о нас.php",
 ),
);